# Show only hovered <v-icon> in Vuetify data table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

i have a Vuetify data table with headers and data field respectively and in the props.item.name i have added a v-icon but i only wanna show that icon only when i hover over that respective field. By default it should not show up.

I have added the Code below with the script and HTML.

And here is a a [pen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/jONKXwa)

Any help will be appreciated on how to achieve that.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Carbs (g)',
          value: 'carbs'
        },
        {
          text: 'Protein (g)',
          value: 'protein'
        },
        {
          text: 'Iron (%)',
          value: 'iron'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.18/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.18/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}
        <v-icon right>cake</v-icon></td>
        <td>{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
        <td>{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a data property called for example  `c_index` (current index) and when you hover over the row you assign the hovered index to `c_index` and reset it to -1 when the mouse the leaves it:

```
  <tr @mouseover="c_index=props.index" @mouseleave="c_index=-1">
```

and show that icon conditionally like :

```
  <v-icon right v-show="props.index==c_index">cake</v-icon>
```

[`Full Demo`](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/QWLxzJm?editors=1010)

Comment: Perfect. however is there any other way than assigning index values?

Comment: Add `@mouseleave="c_index=-1"` to the `<tr>` to also hide the icon when something else than another `<tr>` is hovered.

Comment: there's no pre-built solution, @JKL thanks for this tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a `v-hover` component, inside the `v-slot:item.column_name` of a data table, you can pass a prop through its `v-slot`, and used it like this:

```html
<template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
    <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
        <v-badge
          :value="hover"          
          color="deep-purple accent-4"
          content="First Button"
          left
          transition="slide-x-transition"
         >
             <v-icon>mdi-fountain-pen-tip</v-icon>
         </v-badge>
    </v-hover>
</template>
```

Also you can use the v-hover with the css, but you have to fix the position.
[Full Demo](https://codepen.io/gioalvaro/pen/dyGrLNy)

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is CSS

_ On `v-icon` hover :

```
.v-data-table .v-icon{visibility:hidden}
.v-data-table .v-icon:hover{visibility:visible}
```

_ On `td` container hover

```
.v-data-table td .v-icon{visibility:hidden}
.v-data-table td:hover .v-icon:hover{visibility:visible}
```

This will affect all `v-icon`s in your template, to be more precise add a class to the `v-icon`s you want to  hide.

```
...
<v-icon class="hidden" ... />
...

.hidden{visibility:hidden}
.hidden:hover{visibility:visible}
```

or

```
...
<td class="hidden" >
     <v-icon ...>
...
</td>
...

.hidden .v-icon{visibility:hidden}
.hidden:hover .v-icon{visibility:visible}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i was able to do it using a simple mouseover.native and mouseleave.native

Comment: Your welcome, this will do the work too, but still think adding a data prop, tow events listener, just to emulate what CSS can do by default, is an overkill.